# GeoDjango Changing My Coordinates

Tags: python, geodjango

I'm running into a problem when saving a coordinate into one of my models in (Geo)Django.  My point field is setup as:

```
location = PointField(blank=True, null = True)
```

So while running some tests in the django shell I noticed my coordinates were changing...

```
obj.location = 'POINT(-120.18444970926208 50.65664762026928)'
obj.save()
print(obj.location.x)
```

**-120.1840742**

```
print(obj.location.y)
```

**50.6569673**

Another thing I've noticed If I set the point using an UPDATE in postgres and then...

```
print(obj.location.y)
```

**50.65664762026928**

but if I run a save and check the coordinate again I get...

```
obj.save()
print(obj.location.y)
```

**50.6569673**

Anybody have any ideas where I can start looking to sort this out or any suggestions what may be causing this.

Thanks,
Dustin

Software:

- Django 1.3.1
- GDAL 1.9.1
- Python 2.7.2
- PostGIS 1.5.3
- GEOS 3.3.3
- PostgreSQL 9.1.4

Answer (score 2):

try to add your srid to your point for a more detailed explanation.

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
>>> point_loc = GEOSGeometry('POINT(-120.18444970926208 50.65664762026928)', srid=3084)  
>>> z = Object(location = point_loc)
>>> z.save()
```

i hope it helps you..

Comment: I've defined the SRID before using `'SRID=4326;POINT(-120.18444970926208 50.65664762026928)'` and I also just tried your method with no luck.

Comment: Tracked it down to a bug somewhere else.  Thanks Aragon for the feedback.